# How to parse a field in 2 different ways with Moshi

Tags: json, kotlin, adapter, moshi

I need to parse an object that contains a property "triggers" which is an `List<Trigger>`. This list can contain 2 type of triggers: Custom and Event. 
Here are my Trigger classes :

```
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    open class Trigger(open val type: String,
                       open val source: String,
                       open val tags: Properties? = mutableMapOf())
```

---

```
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class CustomTrigger(override val type: String,
                             override val source: String,
                             override val tags: Properties?,
    //some other fields
    ) : Trigger(type, source, tags)
```

---

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class EventTrigger(override val type: String,
                         override val source: String,
                         override val tags: Properties?,
    //some other fields
) : Trigger(type, source, tags)
```

My object that I receive from server looks like this :

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Rule(val id: String,
                val triggers: MutableList<Trigger>,
//some other fields
)
```

Using generated adapter on parsing I get on triggers only the fields from `Trigger` class. I need to implement a logic to parse an `EventTrigger` is type is "event" or an `CustomTrigger` if type is "custom".

How can I do this with `Moshi`?
Do I need to write a manual parser for my `Rule` object?

Any idea is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example from `Moshi` helped me to solve the parsing problem : 
https://github.com/square/moshi#another-example

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory](http://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi-adapters/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.html).

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder() 
    .add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(HandOfCards.class, "hand_type")
        .withSubtype(BlackjackHand.class, "blackjack")
        .withSubtype(HoldemHand.class, "holdem")) 
    .build();
```

Note that it needs the optional `moshi-adapters` dependency.

Comment: I tried with PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory but it parse it as Trigger in my case, and not in a subclass of Trigger.